# Aptitude Search reports package installed, while Aptitude Show reports it not installed - how is that possible?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, dpkg

```
me@friedly_server:~$ aptitude search samba-tools
i   samba-tools                                      - Samba testing utilities                     


me@friendly_server:~$ aptitude show samba-tools
Package: samba-tools                     
New: yes
State: not installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 2:3.6.6-3
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Debian Samba Maintainers <pkg-samba-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Uncompressed Size: 34.5 M
Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8), libc6 (>= 2.10),     libcap2 (>= 2.10), libcomerr2 (>=
     1.01), libcups2 (>= 1.4.0), libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~), libk5crypto3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libkrb5-3
     (>= 1.10+dfsg~), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libpopt0 (>= 1.14), libreadline6 (>=
     6.0), libtalloc2 (>= 2.0.4~git20101213), libtdb1 (>= 1.2.7+git20101214), libtinfo5, libwbclient0 (>=
     2:3.6.0~pre3), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~)
Conflicts: samba4, samba4-testsuite
Description: Samba testing utilities
 Samba is an implementation of the SMB/CIFS protocol for Unix systems, providing support for cross-platform file
 and printer sharing with Microsoft Windows, OS X, and other Unix systems. 

 This package contains extra command-line tools such as smbtorture for performance-testing CIFS servers and
 clients.
Homepage: http://www.samba.org
```

So, does the 'i' mark in aptitude search contradict to "aptitude show"'s report? Or I don't understand something about that mark's meaning?

Comment: Interesting. What does `dpkg -l | grep samba-tools` show?

Comment: @January $ dpkg -l| grep samba-tools
ii  samba-tools                           2:3.5.11~dfsg-1                Samba testing utilities
it is not in stable release. I've been asking friends now, they say it might be caused by the fact that this package comes from debports: http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=samba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `aptitude search`, you are told that some package called `samba-tools` is installed. When you run `aptitude show`, you are given information about the candidate version of `samba-tools`, i.e. the version that `aptitude install` (or `apt-get install`) would install. On your system, the candidate version is apparently not the version you have installed. Maybe your system is not up-to-date, or maybe you have installed `samba-tools` from an alternate source such as the Debian backports which is only installed on explicit demand.

Comment: Seems, you're perfectly right. The installed version of package appears to be from another release. Unstable and testing repos are enabled in /etc/apt/sources.list. So, 'aptitude show' tells me that 'samba-tools' from *stable* release is not installed, while 'aptitude search' looks through the repos for the packages (and testing and unstable are enabled on *friendlyserver*). Strange, that it doesn't show results for the candidate as well, so that outputs of both commands were consistent.

Comment: @bob in general, you should never mix Debian releases. Doing so is asking for trouble, even with "proper" pinning.